# How do I make HTML textboxes resize relative to the size of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on how to make the two text boxes change size when I shrink the page? So when someone drags the page sideways the two boxes also start to go smaller (if that makes sense). Please could you help me?

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/3nQue/

```
.homeform {
position:relative;
width:20%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the input elements if you want to adjust its size

```
.homeform input[type="email"], .homeform input[type="password"] {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
}
```

if you want that the submit button gets resized too, you can simply shorten the above to the next

```
.homeform input {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
}
```

which will resize all input elements in the elements with `class="homeform"` attribute.

Although i am not a fan of this implementation. Assume that someone on a mobile is visiting your website, the textbox would be too small. (tip : `min-width` property or responsive design)

Answer (score 0):

```
.homeform { width: 100%; }
input[type="text"] { width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box }
```

should do the trick.

box-sizing switches to a box model in which border and padding are contained in the specified width of the element; otherwise you'll have inputs overflow the container here.

Answer (score 0):

`.homeform` is the `div` containing the `input` tags. You must put the style on the `input`.

```
.homeform input{
   width: 20%:
}
```